# Why does my .htaccess not redirect properly from a subfolder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created an .htaccess file to remove the www prefix from domains and also send all requests through a bootstrap (index.php.) Here it is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

My issue is that if the website is contained in a subfolder, the redirect sends the user to the root folder and the redirect breaks down.

Example: User visits "www.example.com/website/news" -> redirected to "example.com/news" (should be "example.com/website/news")

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located, is it inside the `website` subfolder? You might need to set a proper `RewriteBase` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REQUEST_URI` variables instead of `$1` to fix this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I thought this one would work actually. It looks good....

But I'm getting "The page isn't redirecting properly" in my browser

Comment: Specifically, it seems to not be removing the www. and just continous redirecting to the rule over and over.

Comment: You got it. That seemed to fix it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Test this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Although this would probably work, I was hoping for a more dynamic solution that would affect sites both inside subfolders and sites that are not, so that I wouldn't have to edit the htaccess every time I move my sites around. If I can't figure that out, I will go with your solution.

Comment: OK, you want a dynamic solution? but you must be specific in the folder you have a all php code